# Pandas DataFrame .merge not displaying Nan

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame df containing only dates from 2007-01-01 to 2018-04-30 (not as index)
I have a second data frame sub containing dates and values from 2007-01-01 to 2018-04-**20**
I want to have a result data frame res with ALL dates from df and the values from sub at the right place. I am using

```
res = pd.merge(df, sub, on='date', how='outer')
```

I expect to have NaNs from 2018-04-21 to 2018-04-30 in the res data frame.
Instead I got res has only values up to 2018-04-20 (it truncated the missing ones)
Why?

Comment: can you provide a sample data?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, setting indexes and then joining will be useful here:

```
## create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'mdates': pd.date_range('12/13/1989', periods=100, freq='D')})
df['val'] = np.random.randint(10, 500, 100)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'mdates': pd.date_range('12/01/1989', periods=50, freq='D')})

## join data
df1 = df1.set_index('mdates').join(df.set_index('mdates'))

print(df1.head(20))

              val
mdates           
1989-12-01    NaN
1989-12-02    NaN
1989-12-03    NaN
1989-12-04    NaN
1989-12-05    NaN
1989-12-06    NaN
1989-12-07    NaN
1989-12-08    NaN
1989-12-09    NaN
1989-12-10    NaN
1989-12-11    NaN
1989-12-12    NaN
1989-12-13  215.0
1989-12-14  189.0
1989-12-15   97.0
1989-12-16  264.0
1989-12-17  419.0
1989-12-18   57.0
1989-12-19  376.0
1989-12-20  448.0
```